# Deal with a drop_table migration for nonexistent table on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I created a 'campaigns' table in my postgres db in my local env.  I never committed the changes and thus never pushed that to production on heroku.

When I changed my mind about needing that table, I foolishly deleted the migration manually (I know now never to do this).  However, since the migration already had run, I created a `21041211003219_drop_campaigns_table` migration to drop the table from the local db.

Now when I run `heroku run rake db:migrate` on production I get the following error:

```
Migrating to DropCampaignsTable (20141211003219)                                                                                                                                                                                                     
== 20141211003219 DropCampaignsTable: migrating ===============================                                                                                                                                                                      
-- drop_table(:campaigns)                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  table "campaigns" does not exist                                                                                                                                                                                         
: DROP TABLE "campaigns"                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
rake aborted!                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:                                                                                                                                                                        

PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  table "campaigns" does not exist                                                                                                                                                                                         
: DROP TABLE "campaigns"/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:128:in `async_exec'                                                                            
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:128:in `block in execute'
```

I understand that it is trying to run a drop table migration for a table that it never knew existed but I'm unsure on how to handle this.

I tried deleting the drop table migration, pushing to production and running it but it still tried to run that migration.

After rolling back that commit I've been thinking about manually creating a new migration with a datestamp prior to the  `21041211003219_drop_campaigns_table` migration that re-creates the table but then I feel like I'll be left with the table existing in the local postgres db (since the `21041211003219_drop_campaigns_table` has already run locally).

Do I go ahead with the manual creation and then try to re-run the drop migration?

Can someone please advise me on the best course of action here?

Comment: you can recreate your migration from git. Just to be able to get rid of that error you could create a table named campaigns by using `heroku pg:psql`. After this console starts just do 'create table campaigns ...'. Before you do this you should take a backup.

Comment: Why don't you just delete that migration? Migrations aren't meant to be a permanent part of your code, you're supposed to clear them out now and then.

Comment: @Octopus-Paul - +1 I hadn't thought of that and will remember it for next time

Comment: @muistooshort - Although I did try this first (ref in the question), I did attempt this again (didn't push to prod properly first time) and it did work.  I thought you weren't supposed to delete migrations so that anyone else that works on the project in the future can run them and have an accurate DB.  I'm assuming you meant 'clean them out' ref useless ones like the one giving me the problem.  If you want to move to answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just delete the offending migration and get on with more interesting things. Clearly there's no "create table" migration for that table so the "drop table" migration has no right to exist. If you really don't want to delete the migration, you can rewrite it using raw SQL:

```
def up
  connection.execute 'drop table if exists campaigns'
end
```

The `if exists` does exactly what you'd think: it only tries to drop the table if it is there.

About this stuff:

> I thought you weren't supposed to delete migrations so that anyone else that works on the project in the future can run them and have an accurate DB.

Migrations are meant to get an existing instance of an application from state-A to state-B. If you're starting a fresh instance, you'll be using `schema.rb` (or `structure.sql`) to initialize the application and no migrations should be needed. Also, once a migration has been applied to every instance of an application, that migration really isn't needed anymore unless you want to try and go backwards. I tend to clear out old migrations a couple weeks after a release to keep the clutter down.

Answer (score 53):

You can turn off the error `PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  table "campaigns" does not exist` when deleting an already non-existent table by adding `if_exists: true` to `drop_table`:

```
def up
  drop_table(:campaigns, if_exists: true)
end
```

This option is sparsely documented, but exists in Rails [since early 2015](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/18597) and I think it's cleaner than writing SQL by hand as it also handles compatibility with various DB adapters.

Comment: Nice find, I never knew about `if_exists`

Comment: Did not work for me, but this did: `table_exists?(:campaigns) ? drop_table(:campaigns) : nil`

Comment: @MartinSommer - you should make this an answer.

Answer (score 3):

`if_exists` did not work for me with rails 4.2 and PG 9.6. Thanks @MartinSommer for mentioning `table_exists?`. For posterity, this is the syntax I went with, reads a bit cleaner.

`drop_table :campaigns if table_exists?(:campaigns)`

Answer (score 2):

When you're deleting a migration file and you want to drop the corresponding table, e.g. `student_items`, there is two ways:

1. The easy way: restore the migration file to archive and run

   ```sh
   rails db:rollback
   ```
2. Create the migration:

   ```sh
   rails g migration DropStudentItemTable
   ```

   and add this code in the migration file:

   ```rb
   class DropStudentItemTables < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
     def down
       table_exists?(:student_items) ? drop_table(:student_items) : nil
     end
   end
   ```

Comment: thank you, my english is very bad, I'll better my language skill

Answer (score 0):

Plain SQL

```
  def down
    execute <<~SQL
      DROP TABLE IF EXISTS campaigns;
    SQL
  end
```